# How to pass a MonoBehaviour to a static method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry for bad title , I didn't know what exactly should call it.
I have this Code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ScoreBridge : MonoBehaviour {

public static string resultText;

public static string GetScores()
{
    HighscoreSaver.loadScores(this);
    return resultText;
}
public void OnHighscoreLoaded(List<HighscoreSaver.Highscore> highscores)
{
    Debug.Log("Updating highscores!");
    string text = "";
    foreach (HighscoreSaver.Highscore hs in highscores)
    {
        text += hs.name + "\t\t" + hs.score + "\n";
    }
    resultText = text;
}
```

And I need to Run HighscoreSaver.loadScores(this) on GetScores() calls, but I can't use '*this'* keyword in static methods.
any advises are acceptable.
thanks

Comment: Why is GetScores static? Can't you just remove the static keyword from GetScores?

Comment: I need to access GetScores() in another script. that's why it is static.

Comment: If you need acess GetScores() in another script, you can just save the ScoreBridge instance in that script.

Comment: @RicardoReiter I can't instantiate a MonoBehavior  using _new_ keyword

Comment: @user1831943 You can get a reference to an existing instance of it using [`GetComponent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html), or have a public property of type ScoreBridge on your other script and set it in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic way of passing references into static contexts. So you have to pass your ScoreBridge instance to GetScores method, if you really want to make it static.

I think what you want is implementing a singleton design pattern. Take a look at here if you're not familiar with it.

> http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton

Comment: I used singleton and errors gone , but `GetScores()` returns nothing.